# control infinite-loops in php

Tags: php, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have insert some data in mysql via php

this code works:

```
$i = 0;
while($i<6)
{   
    $i++;
    $params['name'] = 'test';
    $last_inserted_id = $database->insert('item',$params);//medoo databaseb lib

}
```

it insert 5 rows in database:

But I have a function that proccess some effect on images. (it return some json code). the function has not any bug.

```
$i = 0;
    while($i<6)
    {   
        $i++;
        $_SESSION["debug_msg"][] ='counter in while:'.$i;  
        $params['name'] = 'test';
        $params['file'] = '';
        if($last_inserted_id = $database->insert('item',$params))
        {
            $proccessImageJson =  proccessImage($last_inserted_id);
            if($proccessImageJson)
            {
                $params['file'] = '$proccessImageJson';
                $database->update(TPREFIX.'item',$params,['id'=>$last_inserted_id]);
            }
        }

    }
```

this code works too...but not with limit for 5! maybe for 40 or 50 or more...

how can I contorl it?

I also try (try/catch) for function section but I got no error.

```
try
{
     if($proccessImageJson =  proccessImage($last_inserted_id))
     {
          $params['file'] = '$proccessImageJson';
          $database->update(TPREFIX.'item',$params,['id'=>$last_inserted_id]);
      }
  }
  catch (SomeException $e)
  {
       ob_start();
       echo 'error:';
       echo $e->getMessage();
       $_SESSION["debug_msg"][] ='function error:'.ob_get_clean();    
  }
```

Finally I count loops with a $_SESSION:

```
$_SESSION["debug_msg"][] ='<br>counter in while :'.$i;
```

it print $i form 1 to 5 and repeat agian and again!

So I think maybe URL calls multi times.

my real address: 
    example.com?id=admin&do=insertdemo

but I changed it whith .htaccess to this:
    example.com/admin/insertdemo

with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&do=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&do=$2 [L,QSA]
```

So I remove .httacess code I call that page with orginall address:

```
example.com?id=admin&do=insertdemo
```

But I got infinite-loops agian...

what is my wrong?

Comment: "it print $i form 1 to 5 and repeat agian and again!" - Is all of this code running inside another loop?

Comment: $params['file'] = '$proccessImageJson'; dont use as string. i mean first of all use double quote not single and in your first if statement use == instead just = and after correcting these syntax and one if condition then see what error you get using error reporting. use == in if($last_inserted_id = $database->insert('item',$params))         {

Comment: @jhmckimm yes....but there is not loop. also I try in for and foreach...

Comment: @SSingh it was a mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK, it should never go in an infinite loop. I can only suggest one thing to you that you try moving the `$i++;` line to the end of the loop instead on in the starting.

The code is going into an infinite loop maybe because there is some error in the code. You can check that by adding following line to the start of the code and then executing it again:

`ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 0):

The loop shown in your question is not infinite. You have a variable called `$i`, an end sign of a natural number and you increase it in each iteration. As a result you have a loop which executes this loop. It can be either in your PHP code or the page might be repeatedly reloaded, or multiple users might be running the same page.

Answer (score 0):

For who want to know how can I solved my problem:

in proccessImage function,I had this form:

```
proccessImage($last_inserted_id)
{
    $this->anotherFunction();
}
```

the reason was `$this->anotherFunction()`

`$this->anotherFunction()` dose not return any value.

I change this:

```
proccessImage($last_inserted_id)
 {
        if($this->anotherFunction())
        { 
            /continue
        }
 }
```

and

```
anotherFunction() /makes images via GD lib
{
    //some code
    return true;
}
```

I do not know why I had loop but with this job,I could solved my problem.